# Network speed came down drastically after update

Tags: networking, apt, upgrade, updates

I am developing a networking application. It was giving 1000Mbps on 24th January, 2019. On 25th January, 2019, I did update using the commands "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade".

Just after the upgrade, the same networking application, I was getting only 400Mbps.

/var/log/apt/history.log is empty.

Is there a way to identify which package has created the issue ?

Comment: I also ran apt upgrade on the same day, and my speed did not change. If your history.log is empty then no package was updated, and your speed change would seem to have a different cause.

Answer (score 0):

one correcting to my posting.

> grep " install " /var/log/apt/history.log

was empty. Not the log.

log is as follows :

---

Start-Date: 2019-01-25  12:24:46
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.485'
Upgrade: libwireshark11:amd64 (2.6.5-1~ubuntu18.10.0, 2.6.6-1~ubuntu18.10.0), libwiretap8:amd64 (2.6.5-1~ubuntu18.10.0, 2.6.6-1~ubuntu18.10.0), libwsutil9:amd64 (2.6.5-1~ubuntu18.10.0, 2.6.6-1~ubuntu18.10.0), wireshark:amd64 (2.6.5-1~ubuntu18.10.0, 2.6.6-1~ubuntu18.10.0), wireshark-common:amd64 (2.6.5-1~ubuntu18.10.0, 2.6.6-1~ubuntu18.10.0), libwscodecs2:amd64 (2.6.5-1~ubuntu18.10.0, 2.6.6-1~ubuntu18.10.0), libwireshark-data:amd64 (2.6.5-1~ubuntu18.10.0, 2.6.6-1~ubuntu18.10.0), wireshark-qt:amd64 (2.6.5-1~ubuntu18.10.0, 2.6.6-1~ubuntu18.10.0)
End-Date: 2019-01-25  12:26:00

Start-Date: 2019-01-25  12:53:26
Commandline: apt -y upgrade
Requested-By: lokesh (1000)
Upgrade: irqbalance:amd64 (1.3.0-0.1build1, 1.3.0-0.1ubuntu0.18.10.1)
End-Date: 2019-01-25  12:53:36

---

as the packages as related to wireshark, I did

> apt remove wireshark
>
> apt install wireshark

Don't know why, but, this resolved the issue. Now I am getting 0.96 Gbps